# How to extract file path from an audio file stored in project resource folder in C#

Tags: c#, audio, directory, resx, wmplib

I am having a problem extracting the file directory of an audio file which is stored in my project resource folder. In my project, I have a mysounds.resx file in which I added a file (abc.mp3).

```
            WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
            wplayer.URL = "E:/xyz.mp3";
            wplayer.settings.setMode("loop",false);
            wplayer.controls.play();
```

Here, when I give the "E:/xyz.mp3" directory in wplayer.URL, it plays fine. But what I want to do is to get the file path from mysounds.resx file in which I stored abc.mp3 and I want to use files paths from mysounds.resx file, not any absolute paths.

Is there anyone who can help me? I am not very good in C#. I really need this work around. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you add the entire MP3 file as a Resource, or did you add a `string` resource with a path to the MP3 file? If it's the former, then  you will have to write the resource to a temporary file, and pass that FilePath as the URL.

Comment: I added the entire MP3 file as a Resource. Can you please refer to any code snipet so that I can understand how to write the resource to a temporary file and pass that FilePath as the URL? I am sorry I am new in C#. It would be so much helpful. Thank you

Comment: See my solution below for a code snippet. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Writing an audio file in a Resource to a temporary file, and then playing it using WMPLib.

```
//Set up the temp path, I'm using a GUID for the file name to avoid any conflicts
var temporaryFilePath = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"), ".mp3") ;

//Your resource accessor, my resource is called AudioFile
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.AudioFile))
using(var tempFileStream = new FileStream(temporaryFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    //Set the memory stream position to 0
    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    //Reads the bytes from the audio file in resource, and writes them to the file
    memoryStream.WriteTo(tempFileStream);
}

//Play your file
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
wplayer.URL = temporaryFilePath;
wplayer.settings.setMode("loop", false);
wplayer.controls.play();

//Delete the file after use
if(File.Exists(temporaryFilePath))
    File.Delete(temporaryFilePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

**a) OK, first add audio file (.wav) into project resource.**

1. Open "Solution Explorer" from menu toolbar ("VIEW") or simply press Ctrl+Alt+L.
2. Click on drop-down list of "Properties".
3. Then select "Resource.resx" and press enter.

[image: open project resource]

4. Now select "Audio" from the combobox list.

[image: add audio files to resource]

5. Then click on "Add Resource", choose audio files (.wav) and click "Open".

[image: browsing for audio files]

6. Select audio file(s) and change "Persistence" properties to "Embedded in .resx".

[image: embedding audio files to resource]

**b) Now, just write this code to play the audio.**

In this code I'm playing audio on form load event.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Media; // at first you've to import this package to access SoundPlayer

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class login : Form
    {
        public login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            playaudio(); // calling the function
        }

        private void playaudio() // defining the function
        {
            SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.Connect); // here WindowsFormsApplication1 is the namespace and Connect is the audio file name
            audio.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

That it.
All done, now run the project (press f5) and enjoy your sound.
All the best, Good bye. :)